# Memcached or MySQL for session storage - PHP

Tags: mysql, session, memcached

Is it good idea to use Memcached for session storage with PHP? We will have a lot of servers and we must access the session data from everywhere so we are forced to use database (in our case that will be MySQL) as session storage or Memcached. What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know people who've used Memcached for this -- it's very fast, certainly a lot faster than a database, and is built to handle a lot more concurrency.

The primary disadvantage to purely in-memory storage is that all your session data will be wiped if/when you restart the daemon. In my experience, memcached is rock-solid and I've never had to restart it because of a failure, but it is a consideration if your sysadmins aren't used to working that way, or if your systems are updated frequently. It also depends on whether losing all your user sessions once a month or year is acceptable or not (i.e. in ecommerce, management probably won't like this).

The obvious solution, if that's the case, is to go to one of the many disk-based NoSQL/hash table databases, such as [MemcacheDB](http://memcachedb.org/), which is based off of Memcached. Or see: [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) etc. Each of these daemons (including Memcached) is also a lot less complex when it comes to performance tuning than MySQL (where all sorts of things like key and sort buffers, query cache etc. have to be tuned per install/use case) -- I mean, with Memcached there's not much to do other than to allocate memory and start it up.

Personally, I am a fan of using faster, more appropriate (non-SQL) storage for temporary things like session keys, but if your database is not under load and you don't anticipate it to be, the only thing you lose by storing sessions in the database is that it's a little slower, so users see a little more latency.

Whichever way you go, I suggest that you write your session-management code in such a way that the storage engine is just a layer, and you can swap in a different storage engine relatively painlessly. You don't want to be recoding your application if you find memcached or whatever you choose isn't working well, and you want to try something else. For instance, I once wrote a caching system for a clustered CMS application that used memcached to cache various pages and objects, but when the daemon wasn't reachable, it would fail over to alternate backends that would cache to shared memory or disk on the individual webservers. (In your case, you don't necessarily need the auto-failover, just the ability to change your mind about the backend.)

I mentioned MemcacheDB because it uses the Memcache protocol, so it's extremely easy to swap in Memcached for MemcacheDB or vice versa.